# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/bcel/classfile/Visitor

Tags: java, ant, ivy, antbuilder

I am trying to build the application but I am getting this error :
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/bcel/classfile/Visitor

I have added the jar in ivy.xml

```
<dependency org="org.apache.bcel" name="bcel" rev="6.7.0"/>
```

But, When I am doing Ant build it is giving error.

I tried with other version as well , added this as well :

```
<jar destfile="output/atut.jar" duplicate="preserve" comment="Version: ${version}, Status: ${status}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Version" value="${version}"/>
                <attribute name="Status" value="${status}"/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset refid="atut.classes"/>
           
            <fileset dir="classes/Core"/>
            
            <fileset dir="lib/compile">
                <include name="bcel.jar"/>
            </fileset>
            
        </jar>
```

But, still unable to build it.